# Python - FFT of 2D correlation function: is it the 2D power spectrum?

Tags: python, fft

I have a density field on a 2d grid. I have a matrix that describes the "correlation" of each point of the grid with all the other points. For example, let's say that I have a 4x4 grid, whose points I label with these indices:

```
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8 
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

then I have a matrix which is 16x16. The first row describes the correlation of pixel 1 with all the others, the second row describes the correlation of pixel 2 with all the others and so on until row 16. Symbolically:

```
1-1  1-2  1-3 ...... 1-16
2-1  2-2  2-3 ...... 2-16
.
.
.
16-1 16-2 16-3...... 16-16
```

If I use a 2-dimensional FFT of this matrix (np.fft.fft2) do I get a quantity which is the density field power spectrum? Or do I have to do some extra operation on the matrix before applying the FFT, such as reordering the entries according to some rules, or padding extra entries with zeros?

Comment: What do you mean by "correlation" in this context?  (i.e. what mathematical operation are you applying to obtain each element from the 4x4 input matrix?)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth let's say I want to calculate element 1-2 of the correlation matrix. In pricniple I should take the average over different realisations of the density field of the product of the density in pixel 1 and pixl 2. In practice, I have already these quantities, they have been precomputed